# Update ExceptionNonQuery

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledbconnection

I am trying to update an MS Access table and it keeps throwing an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Syntax error in string in query expression 'EmID = '234'.

The `EmID` is in the database. Please help

```
public partial class Sales : Form
{
    ...
    private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int EmpID = int.Parse(txtEmpID.Text);

        OleDbConnection con = new     OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\SalesData.mdb");

        OleDbCommand update = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Sales SET Printer = '" + txtPrinter.Text + "', Ink = '" +txtInk.Text + "', Paper = '"+txtPaper.Text+"' WHERE EmID = '" + txtEmpID.Text + " ", con);

        con.Open();
        update.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Sales Updated");
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have forgotten to add a closing quote after the WHERE value. But fixing the problem adding the missing quote serves only to hide other problems.

What if one of your textboxes contains a single quote? You will get again a syntax error exception caused by the string concatenation where the quotes serve as delimiter of your values. With a single quote typed by your user you will confuse the Sql Parser again.

To fix this problem (and a more serious one called Sql Injection) you need to start using parameters

```
string cmdText = @"UPDATE Sales SET Printer = @printer,
                   Ink = @Ink, Paper = @Paper 
                   WHERE EmID = @id";

using(OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(...))
using(OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, con))
{
    con.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@printer", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txtPrinter.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ink", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txtInk.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@paper", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txtPaper.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txtEmpID.Text;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm still getting an error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Syntax error in UPDATE statement

Comment: @MattBrown: There's an extra, unneeded **comma** `,` after the `Paper = @Paper,` just before the `WHERE` clause - if you remove that one, you should be good to go

Comment: I like the stack overflow community how everyone helps new developer to prevent basis database attacks like SQL injection.

Comment: @marc_s  I am now get this error:"No value given for one or more required parameters." I filled out the the form with the right EmID and every box had a value. Am i forgetting something?

Comment: Check if you have not mispelled some column names or the table name

Comment: AWESOME guys it worked. I made a sloppy mistake of not activating the click action on the text boxes. Thank all so much. I am now going to attempt to have a button that will bring the total sales of the EmID. Any ideas? @steve

Comment: Probably the best course of action is posting another question with the new details that your effort requires. But do not forget to add your tries and your code in case of problems.